# height and bisector in a right triangle

Tags: triangles

We have right angle $ABC$ where $AB$ is hypotenuse, and angle bisector $CD$ we know that $AB=c$, $CD=u$. Express height depending on the $c, u$, and what is the condition between $c,u$ that the triangle $ABC$ exist?

I have some problems here I tried to enter new viariable $a,b$ and use Pythagorean theorem and the bisector theorem, but without success.

Comment: What is $CD$ bisecting?  $AB$ or $\angle C?$  Which altitude are you trying to express-the one from $C$?

Comment: $CD$ devide $\angle C$ on equal parts

Comment: If C is right angle, u=c/2, so your question may be not correct.

Comment: no, $u\neq\frac{c}{2}$ u is angle bisector section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $BC=x$. Noting that $AC=\sqrt{c^2-x^2}$, let us consider the areas. Let $(A)$ be the area of a figure $A$.

$$(\text{a triangle}\ ABC)=(\text{a triangle}\ BCD)+(\text{a triangle}\ ACD)$$
$$\Rightarrow\ \frac 12x\sqrt{c^2-x^2}=\frac 12xu\sin\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac 12u\sqrt{c^2-x^2}\sin\frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$\Rightarrow\ 2x\sqrt{c^2-x^2}=\sqrt2 xu+\sqrt 2u\sqrt{c^2-x^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow\ \sqrt{c^2-x^2}(2x-\sqrt2u)=\sqrt 2xu$$
$$\Rightarrow\ (c^2-x^2)(2x-\sqrt 2u)^2=2x^2u^2$$
$$\Rightarrow\ 2x^4-2\sqrt2ux^3+(u^2-2c^2)x^2+2\sqrt 2uc^2x-c^2u^2=0$$
$$\Rightarrow\ (x-c)(x+c)(\sqrt2x-u)^2=0$$
$$\Rightarrow\ x=c\ \text{or}\ x=-c\ \text{or}\ x=\frac{u}{\sqrt2}.$$

By the way, $x=\pm c$ are not what we want because of $AC=\sqrt{c^2-x^2}.$ Hence, the answer should be $x=\frac{u}{\sqrt2}$.

In addition, the condition that a triangle can exist is that 
$$c^2-x^2\gt0\ \iff\ c^2-\frac{u^2}{2}\gt0\ \iff\ u^2\lt 2c^2\ \iff\ u\lt \sqrt 2c\ \iff\ \frac{u}{c}\lt \sqrt 2.$$

Considering ares is sometimes useful.

Comment: but, why are you assume that $CD$ is median?

Comment: I misunderstood it. Now I hope I'm not mistaken.